# Mocking DynamoDB in Spark with Mockito

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mockito, amazon-dynamodb, scalatest

I want to mock Utilities function dynamoDBStatusWrite so that when my spark program will run, it will not hit the DynamoDB.

Below is my mocking and test case stuff

```scala
class FileConversion1Test extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar with Matchers with ArgumentMatchersSugar with SparkSessionTestWrapper {
  "File Conversion" should "convert the file to" in {

    val utility = mock[Utilities1]
    val client1 = mock[AmazonDynamoDB]
    val dynamoDB1 =mock[DynamoDB]
    val dynamoDBFunc = mock[Utilities1].dynamoDBStatusWrite("test","test","test","test")
    val objUtilities1 = new Utilities1

    FieldSetter.setField(objUtilities1,objUtilities1.getClass.getDeclaredField("client"),client1)
    FieldSetter.setField(objUtilities1,objUtilities1.getClass.getDeclaredField("dynamoDB"),dynamoDB1)

    FieldSetter.setField(objUtilities1,objUtilities1.getClass.getField("dynamoDBStatusWrite"),dynamoDBFunc)

    when(utility.dynamoDBStatusWrite("test","test","test","test")).thenReturn("pass")

    assert(FileConversion1.fileConversionFunc(spark,"src/test/inputfiles/userdata1.csv","parquet","src/test/output","exec1234567","service123")==="passed")

  }
}
```

My spark program should not try to connect dynamoDB. but is trying to connect

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems there, for starters the fact that you mock something doesn't replace it automatically in your system, you need to build your software so components are injected and so in the test you would be providing a mock version of them. ie, `fileConversionFunc` should receive another parameter with the connector to Dynamo.

That said, it's considered a bad practice to mock library/3rd party classes, what you should do there is to create your own component that encapsulates the interaction with Dynamo, and then mock your component, as it's an API you control.
You can find a detailed explanation of why [here](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own)